# Azure Security Center Recommendations On Deleted Resources

Tags: azure

We are using Azure Security Center to monitor our subscriptions for compliance. It is flagging a couple deleted Azure SQL Databases for Authentication And Authorization problems. When I click on the resource name to view more details I get error "Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource 'server/database' not found."

How do I clear these vulnerabilities from Security Center? I cannot create an exemption, force a new scan, or do the remediation steps because the resource does not exist. I thought Azure would eventually figure out these resources have been deleted and clear the recommendations since they are no longer applicable but it has been months and the recommendations are still showing as unhealthy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a known issue:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/247247/azure-security-center-giving-recommandation-for-de.html

In January the message was:

> The product group is aware about this and working towards fixing it.
> You should not see this from next week or so.

Comment: That's disappointing. Thanks for the information